# visual studio 2015 update3 can't watch local variables sometimes

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, uwp, watch

[can't seem local variable in local scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvYWf.png)

[cann't watch local variable's value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Xrm.png)

```
  private byte[] sizeBytes;
public async Task<string> ReceiveStream()
{
    byte[] responseBytes;
    string response=null;
    try
    {
        await m_dataReader.LoadAsync(4);
        sizeBytes=new byte[4];
        m_dataReader.ReadBytes(sizeBytes);
        int len = int.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sizeBytes)) ;

        // 读内容
        responseBytes = new byte[len];
        m_dataReader.UnicodeEncoding=UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        await m_dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)len);
        response= m_dataReader.ReadString(m_dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        Debug.Log(response.Length);
        Debug.Log(response);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return response; //返回response

}
```

the code is above,only member variable can be seen in watch view.
This is a UWP Project export from Unity3D.

Comment: On the first image did you mean it should display detail string instead of `System.Text.UTF8Encoding`?  On the second image did you mean the `response` and `respones` should show the value?  What the `Debug.log` come from? UWP app doesn't have this method at default.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT yes,I can't see local variable in Local And Watch Window. Debug.Log is Unity3D's API.The Project is exported from Unity3D to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer,but I don't think there is a way to solve it.
This Project is exported from Unity3d.
When I add 'async' keyword before method name,the local window in Debuging Mode is messy.
[image]

[image]